# segmentation fault after strtok function

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, strtok

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

bool kill_self = false;

void my_signal_handler(int signum, siginfo_t* info, void* ptr){
    // register action for SIGINT (find out my pid and kill self if kill_self)
    printf("Signal sent from process %lu\n", (unsigned long)info->si_pid);
    if (kill_self){ //kill_self will surely be updated correctly?
        kill(getpid(), SIGKILL); //return int - for check?
    }
}

int prepare(){
    struct sigaction new_action;
    memset(&new_action, 0, sizeof(new_action));
    new_action.sa_sigaction = my_signal_handler;
    new_action.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    //register handler
    if (0 != sigaction(SIGINT, &new_action, NULL)){
        printf("Signal handler registration %s\n failed", strerror(errno)); 
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
if (prepare() != 0)
    exit(-1);

while (1)
{
    char** arglist = NULL;
    char* line = NULL;
    size_t size;
    int count = 0;

    if (getline(&line, &size, stdin) == -1) {
        printf("getline failed\n");
        free(line);
        break;
    }

    arglist = (char**) malloc(sizeof(char*));
    if (arglist == NULL) {
        printf("malloc failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        exit(-1);
    }

    arglist[0] = strtok(line, " \t\n");

    while (arglist[count] != NULL) {
        printf("in while\n");
        ++count;
        arglist = (char**) realloc(arglist, sizeof(char*) * (count + 1));
        if (arglist == NULL) {
            printf("realloc failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
            exit(-1);
        }
        arglist[count] = strtok(NULL, " \t\n");
    }

    //continue code...
```

For the line `mkdir new` (just an example) - main function at the end of the code shown here goes through 2 while loops before comparing again the condition (`arglist[count] != NULL`) and getting in segmentation fault.

The weird thing is, that without the other functions, main works fine with no segmentation fault.
Does anybody have an idea? Debugging doesn't help...

Comment: did you try initializing size to 0? When the buffer pointer is null, size needs to be set to 0 otherwise it may stomp on memory.

Comment: "If *lineptr is set to NULL and *n is set 0 before the call",  - per the documentation, affirming what Garr said.

Comment: Please don't cast malloc in C language, it can only hide interesting warnings like indirection level errors.

Comment: The code as posted doesn't exhibit any invalid behavior.  The error is in a part of the code you haven't posted.  Try running your code through [valgrind](http://valgrind.org).  If you're stepping on memory you shouldn't be, it will tell you.

Answer (score 2):

You are using an uninitialized variable. This causes a subtle error depending on the initial value and length of your input stream.

`getline` works like this:

- read characters from stream until a newline or we hit our size limit
- reallocate buffer if needed for more characters, or return if newline
- repeat

So, if the initial value of size is 0, the first thing it does is reallocate, using the null value for 'line' and gets a new buffer.  But, if size is not 0, it stomps on memory. That may not be a problem until later, but once memory is corrupted, it's done.

Comment: There is no corruption here.  `getline` is called once, and the first parameter points to a NULL pointer.  So the valid pointed to by the second parameter is ignored and overwritten.

Comment: we have no information on which system he is running on. getline as documented must have size set to 0, so on your system it may implement that way, but according to documentation that is an invalid use of getline.

Comment: It seems it depends on which documentation you're looking at.  [This](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getline) says the value of `*n` is ignored if `*lineptr` is NULL (as does my local man pages), while [this](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) says `*n` should be 0 in that case.  So it depends on what you consider to be authoritative.

Comment: regardless, it should be initialized. Obviously, it might work on some platforms either way.